# True/false : If $f_n(x)\to 0$ almost everywhere , then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is the following sttaement is true/false ?

> let {$f_n$} be sequence of integrable functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$.
>
> If $f_n(x)\to 0$ almost everywhere , then $\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx \to 0$

My attempt : i know that $m(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$  and $f(\mathbb{Q}) =0$  is almost everywhere because the  $f$ is not going to $0$ and measure is $0$ in $[0,1]$

Now consider the function $f_n(x)$, on the interval $[0,1]$. Let $\{r_1, r_2, \dots\}
$ is the enumerarion of rationals on $[0,1]$.

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{x = $r_1, r_2, \dots r_n$} \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Thus $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$, which is $0$ almost everywhere

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\0 & x \in [0,1] - \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\end{cases}$$

But $\int_0^1 f(x)$ does not exists.

so the given statement is false

Is its true ?

Comment: Why do you say $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ does not exist?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual counterexample is something like $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}n & x \in (0, 1/n] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: ur $f_n(x)  \rightarrow  \infty $???? @angryavian,,,,,my question is $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ read question again

Comment: @jasmine No, $f_n(x) \to 0$. For example, if $x=0.1$, then $f_n(x) = 0$ for any $n > 10$.

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance the sequence $f_n=n1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

If you want smooth functions as a counterexample, try $f_n(x)=nx^n$ on $[0,1].$

Comment: im little bit confused @zhw  at $x= 1$ ur $f_n(x)$ does not tend to $0$

Comment: @jasmine, read ur own question again: it says that $f_n\to 0$ _almost everywhere_.